Trying to create a contract for Aave... failing miserably!
I am trying to create a contract so that it deposits wsteth on the scroll pool whenever there is availability.
import time
from web3 import Web3
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware
from eth_account import Account
from eth_abi import decode_abi

# Configuration
RPC_URL = "https://rpc.scroll.io/"
AAVE_POOL_ADDRESS = "0x11fCfe756c05AD438e312a7fd934381537D3cFfe"
WSTETH_ADDRESS = "0xf610A9dfB7C89644979b4A0f27063E9e7d7Cda32"
PRIVATE_KEY = "xxxxxxxx"  # Directly input your private key here
CHECK_INTERVAL = 20  # Check every 20 seconds

# Ensure PRIVATE_KEY is a valid 64-character hexadecimal string
if len(PRIVATE_KEY) != 64 or not all(c in '0123456789abcdefABCDEF' for c in PRIVATE_KEY):
    raise ValueError("Invalid private key format. It should be a 64-character hexadecimal string.")

# Initialize Web3
print("Initializing Web3 connection...")
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(RPC_URL))
web3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)

# Derive account from private key
print("Deriving account from private key...")
account = Account.from_key(PRIVATE_KEY)
address = account.address
print(f"Using account: {address}")

# ABI Definitions
ERC20_ABI = [
    {
        "constant": True,
        "inputs": [{"name": "_owner", "type": "address"}],
        "name": "balanceOf",
        "outputs": [{"name": "balance", "type": "uint256"}],
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": False,
        "inputs": [{"name": "_spender", "type": "address"}, {"name": "_value", "type": "uint256"}],
        "name": "approve",
        "outputs": [{"name": "success", "type": "bool"}],
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": True,
        "inputs": [{"name": "_owner", "type": "address"}, {"name": "_spender", "type": "address"}],
        "name": "allowance",
        "outputs": [{"name": "remaining", "type": "uint256"}],
        "type": "function"
    }
]

AAVE_POOL_ABI = [
    {
        "constant": False,
        "inputs": [
            {"name": "asset", "type": "address"},
            {"name": "amount", "type": "uint256"},
            {"name": "onBehalfOf", "type": "address"},
            {"name": "referralCode", "type": "uint16"}
        ],
        "name": "supply",
        "outputs": [],
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": True,
        "inputs": [{"name": "asset", "type": "address"}],
        "name": "getReserveData",
        "outputs": [
            {"name": "configuration", "type": "uint256"},
            {"name": "liquidityIndex", "type": "uint128"},
            {"name": "currentLiquidityRate", "type": "uint128"},
            {"name": "variableBorrowIndex", "type": "uint128"},
            {"name": "currentVariableBorrowRate", "type": "uint128"},
            {"name": "currentStableBorrowRate", "type": "uint128"},
            {"name": "lastUpdateTimestamp", "type": "uint40"},
            {"name": "id", "type": "uint16"},
            {"name": "aTokenAddress", "type": "address"},
            {"name": "stableDebtTokenAddress", "type": "address"},
            {"name": "variableDebtTokenAddress", "type": "address"},
            {"name": "interestRateStrategyAddress", "type": "address"},
            {"name": "availableLiquidity", "type": "uint256"},
            {"name": "totalPrincipalStableDebt", "type": "uint256"},
            {"name": "averageStableRate", "type": "uint256"},
            {"name": "stableDebtLastUpdateTimestamp", "type": "uint40"},
            {"name": "totalScaledVariableDebt", "type": "uint256"},
            {"name": "variableRateSlope1", "type": "uint256"},
            {"name": "variableRateSlope2", "type": "uint256"},
            {"name": "stableRateSlope1", "type": "uint256"},
            {"name": "stableRateSlope2", "type": "uint256"}
        ],
        "type": "function"
    }
]

def check_balance():
    wsteth_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=WSTETH_ADDRESS, abi=ERC20_ABI)
    balance = wsteth_contract.functions.balanceOf(address).call()
    print(f"Checked wstETH balance: {balance}")
    return balance

def check_allowance():
    wsteth_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=WSTETH_ADDRESS, abi=ERC20_ABI)
    allowance = wsteth_contract.functions.allowance(address, AAVE_POOL_ADDRESS).call()
    print(f"Checked wstETH allowance: {allowance}")
    return allowance

def get_aave_cap():
    pool = web3.eth.contract(address=AAVE_POOL_ADDRESS, abi=AAVE_POOL_ABI)
    try:
        reserve_data = pool.functions.getReserveData(WSTETH_ADDRESS).call()
        # Decode and print the values to check what is being returned
        cap = reserve_data[12]  # Index for availableLiquidity
        print(f"Checked Aave cap: {cap}")
        return cap
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while fetching Aave cap: {e}")
        return 0

def approve_wsteth(amount):
    print(f"Approving {amount} wstETH for Aave Lending Pool...")
    wsteth_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=WSTETH_ADDRESS, abi=ERC20_ABI)
    tx = wsteth_contract.functions.approve(AAVE_POOL_ADDRESS, amount).buildTransaction({
        'chainId': web3.eth.chain_id,
        'gas': 70000,
        'gasPrice': web3.toWei('0.085', 'gwei'),
        'nonce': web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address)
    })
    signed_tx = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, PRIVATE_KEY)
    tx_hash = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
    receipt = web3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
    print(f"Approved {amount} wstETH for Aave Lending Pool. Transaction hash: {tx_hash.hex()}")

def deposit_wsteth(amount):
    print(f"Depositing {amount} wstETH to Aave Lending Pool...")
    pool = web3.eth.contract(address=AAVE_POOL_ADDRESS, abi=AAVE_POOL_ABI)
    tx = pool.functions.supply(WSTETH_ADDRESS, amount, address, 0).buildTransaction({
        'chainId': web3.eth.chain_id,
        'gas': 120000,
        'gasPrice': web3.toWei('0.085', 'gwei'),
        'nonce': web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address)
    })
    signed_tx = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, PRIVATE_KEY)
    tx_hash = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
    receipt = web3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
    print(f"Deposited {amount} wstETH to Aave Lending Pool. Transaction hash: {tx_hash.hex()}")

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            print("Starting new check cycle...")
            balance = check_balance()
            allowance = check_allowance()
            aave_cap = get_aave_cap()
            amount_to_deposit = min(balance, int(aave_cap * 0.95))
            
            if amount_to_deposit > 0:
                print(f"Balance: {balance} wstETH, Aave Cap: {aave_cap} wstETH")
                print(f"Will deposit up to {amount_to_deposit} wstETH to Aave Lending Pool.")
                
                if allowance < amount_to_deposit:
                    approve_wsteth(amount_to_deposit)
                
                deposit_wsteth(amount_to_deposit)
            else:
                print("No wstETH available to deposit or no cap available in Aave.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        print(f"Sleeping for {CHECK_INTERVAL} seconds before next check...")
        time.sleep(CHECK_INTERVAL)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

The error im getting is
Starting new check cycle...
Checked wstETH balance: 100000000000000000
Checked wstETH allowance: 100000000000000000
An error occurred: Could not decode contract function call to getReserveData with return data: b'\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x03\xe8\x00\x00\x04\xa3\x80\x00\x00\x10h\x05\xdc\x85\x12)\xcc\x1ex\x1dL\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03;o\xc0dwE\xc3\'\x9d\xdd\xb1\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x08\xf2\xf2M\xe6\xa7#Y\x03\xd0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03>lBz\xb9\xd0\xfa"\r\xdf\xfc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1b\x9b\x96\xf2\x1c\xdfy\x02c\xcc\xfb\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00f\xac\xe4\xb0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00[\x13"\xee\xb4b@\xb0. \x06+\x8f\x0f\x99\x08\xd5%\xb0\x9c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\xe3\xf1%\xce\x85\xe8\xd6Z\xd2\xbbOk_\xff\x11\x07r\xa0x\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8a\x03VD2!)\x80\x0c?t\x7fT\xdb\x0fM<\n(w\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xec\x93\xd0\xbb\xa1\xb1\xe65\xba\x0f\xffG\x86\xdb2=\xb4\x9d\x99\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x05\x03\x12\xd2g\xf8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', output_types: ['uint256', 'uint128', 'uint128', 'uint128', 'uint128', 'uint128', 'uint40', 'uint16', 'address', 'address', 'address', 'address', 'uint256', 'uint256', 'uint256', 'uint40', 'uint256', 'uint256', 'uint256', 'uint256', 'uint256']
Sleeping for 20 seconds before next check...

I've tried so many things with chatgpt/gemini. seems impossible that they are going to help me resolve it...
